# dijit.byId returns undefined

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a hidden form and I am trying to put it into a variable via dijit.byId
Unfortunately it always returns undefined.

Am I missing something? dojo is flummoxing me at every corner - any help much appreciated.

js:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
var regForm = dijit.byId("hiddenRegister");
//regForm is undefined
});
```

html:

```
<div id="hiddenRegister" dojoType="dijit.form.Form"  jsId="hiddenRegister" encType="multipart/form-data" action="" method=""></div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Try with Firebug to log regForm with console.dir(regForm); if you can't make it work, probably you have not imported correctly dojo toolkit.

Comment: Thanks - needed to add djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"

Answer (score 2):

id and jsId should not be the same

and if you are using jsId, then there is no need for dijit.byId. The widget is already assigned to a variable using the jsId as the variable name.